# Edições nos wikis de tags, se aprovadas, vale pontos?

Tags: suporte

Vi que foi criada uma tag para a linguagem de programação ADVPL, inclusive eu havia feito a proposta de criação dessa tag. Aproveitei para editar a tag, acrescentando algumas informações. A edição ainda não foi aprovada, mas gostaria de saber se edições nos wikis de tags, se aprovadas, vale pontos?

Comment: Sim, vale 2 pontos.